# Firebase integration with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
string RegId = "************";
string ApplicationID = "*****";
string SENDER_ID = "***";
var value = "sandeepweb"; //message text box

WebRequest tRequest;
tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"); tRequest.Method = "post";
tRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", ApplicationID)); tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
//Data post to the Server
string postData =
"collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message="
+ value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() +
"&registration_id=" + RegId + "";
Console.WriteLine(postData);

Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse(); dataStream =  tResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();  //Get response from GCM server  

tReader.Close(); dataStream.Close();
tResponse.Close();
lblsuccess.Text = sResponseFromServer;
```

App Crashes When i send any notification. Notifications are sent from Firebase console. Do I need to make some changes in above code?

Comment: What error do you get? Have you tried wrapping your code in a try-catch-block to get more info?

Comment: Could you provide an error message as well as the line it occurs with? It's next to impossible to give you an answer with merely a code dump

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp). it uses `Firebase REST API` behind the scenes and make your queries easy and felxible. You dont have to deal with a large messy code

**Push Example**:

```
var todo = new Todo {
                name = "Execute PUSH",
                priority = 2
            };
PushResponse response =await  _client.PushAsync("todos/push", todo);
response.Result.name //The result will contain the child name of the new data that was added
```